# Multiple plots on python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot a curve on an image.
I would to see the curve only in a certain range.
So:

```
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img)
plt.plot(x, my_curve)
plt.axis([0, X, Y, 0])
```

But in this way also the image is showed in that range, but I don't want this.
I would like to see the whole image with a portion of the curve.
How can apply the axes only on the second plot?

EDIT: I can't use a slice of the arrays. I am in this case (it is an example):

```
x        = [0 0 0 10 10 10 30 30 30 40 40 40]
my_curve = [0 0 0 10 10 10 30 30 30 40 40 40]
```

Well I need to see the straight line only between 25 and 35. If I delete each element out of such range, I obtain only the point (30,30).

Comment: Have you tried plotting a slice of the `x` and `my_curve` in `plt.plot(x, my_curve)` to something like `plt.plot(x[:X], my_curve[:X])`?

Comment: I can't do this. my_curve derives by an interpolation. And considering only my_curve[0:X] I lose significant information (I can't reproduce the line)

Comment: This changes things slightly -- you could search for the index of `X` in `x` (we'll call it `X_idx`) and then do `plt.plot(x[:X_idx], my_curve[:X_idx])`.

Comment: Good answer, but it does not work. See my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just restrict your data : `plt.plot(x[0:X], my_curve[0:X])`.

**EDIT**

If your data is sparse, you can interpolate it :

```
x2=linspace(x[0],x[-1],1000)[0:X]
my_curve2=np.interp(x2,x,my_curve)
plt.plot(x2, my_curve2)
```

Comment: I can't, because my_curve is an interpolated data.